# Apply a self-made function with mutate across

Tags: r, function, dplyr, data-wrangling, mutate

I have created a function and I want to create new variables according to the conditions of the self-made function but I get mistakes...

This is my function:

```
percentages <- function(x) {
  mutate(x = case_when(
    x < 25 ~ "Menos 25%",
    x <50 ~ "Entre 30% 50%", 
    x <75 ~ "Entre 50% 75%",
    x >= 75 ~ "Más 75%")
  )
  return(x)
}
```

When I apply this code:

```
transp6 <- transp_articles %>% mutate
(across(c(perc_index_info_inst_org:perc_index_art_10_portal), percentages))
```

I get this result:

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = across(...)`.
x no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

When I apply this:

```
transp6 <- transp_articles %>% 
mutate(across 
(.cols = c(perc_index_info_inst_org:perc_index_art_10_portal), 
.fns = percentages(c(perc_index_info_inst_org:perc_index_art_10_portal)),
.names = "{.col}_rank"))
```

I get this:

rror: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = across(...)`.
x no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"

```
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = across(...)`.
i numerical expression has 1031 elements: only the first used 
 Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = across(...)`.
x no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Finally, I try to do it with an apply:

```
apply(transp_articles$perc_index_info_inst_org:transp_articles$perc_index_art_10_portal, 
margin = 2, percentages)
```

And I get:

> Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default

Comment: What is `transp_articles`? It seems to be a character vector. `mutate` only takes data.frame as input.

Comment: @DarrenTsai transp_articles is a data.frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're passing a `mutate` to a `mutate`; `across` takes functions like `case_when` that accepts a vector and returns a vector. Easiest like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

transp6 <- 
  transp_articles |>
  mutate(across(perc_index_info_inst_org:perc_index_art_10_portal,
                ~ case_when(
                  . < 25 ~ "Menos 25%",
                  . < 50 ~ "Entre 30% 50%", 
                  . < 75 ~ "Entre 50% 75%",
                  . >= 75 ~ "Más 75%"
  )))
```

Alternatively, define your function:

```r
percentages <- function(x) {
  
  case_when(
    x < 25 ~ "Menos 25%",
    x < 50 ~ "Entre 30% 50%", 
    x < 75 ~ "Entre 50% 75%",
    x >= 75 ~ "Más 75%")
  )
  
}
```

And then:

```
library(dplyr)

transp6 <-
  transp_articles |>
  mutate(across(.cols = perc_index_info_inst_org:perc_index_art_10_portal, 
                .fns = percentages,
                .names = "{.col}_rank"))
```

Without reproducible data I cannot make you a working example.

**Edit**: Bug fix + add example with across with the names argument as OP.

Comment: It works!!! Thank you really much! And how could I do it applying a function?

Comment: See update :-) The subsetting syntax is different in `base` than `dplyr` (you'll have to look that up), but the usage is straight-forward: `lapply(transp_articles, percentages)`.